# How to export animated object using NurbsPath to Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx

I work with Blender 2.8 and create a 3D animation using Path. How can I export my animation as .fbx to my unity project. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to program the animation with armature and bones (which can have a follow path constraint). Then in pose mode go to the 3D window menu "Pose-Animation-Bake Action", and bake your animation checking the "Visual keying" and "Clear constraints" options.